# What is the EASIEST/QUICKIEST way to generate an android APK using Felgo Qt Creator?

Tags: android, qt, apk, felgo

There is no such android options and menus here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28292048/5648245 :(

Duplicate? [Issues to build apk with qt creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713738/issues-to-build-apk-with-qt-creator) why there is no answer there after one year!?

At menu "Tools/Options/Kits" the only auto detected is felgo desktop gcc.

Obs.: I can't stand watching videos with instructions in case there is any...

ps.: I am using Qt Creator 4.11.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

---

update:

I tried gradle as specified here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode
with: `gradle assembleDebug`
but there is no such task as I confirm with `gradle tasks --all`.

also there is an `android` path with these files:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
build.gradle
```

and `gradle tasks` there outputs this error:
`Could not get unknown property 'androidCompileSdkVersion' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.`

I think I need to install android compiler? I will research more later...

Comment: Just do a Gradle build: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Comment: @paulsm4 thx, I am trying to follow that instructions, I think I need some android dependencies to try to build it? I will try more later.

Comment: I've never used anything but Eclipse (and later, AndroidStudio) to build .apks.  Under the covers, the latter uses "gradle", and the former used "ant".  I assumed you were able to build *SOMETHING* using QT Creator.  If so, then you *should* already have everything (Java compiler, Android SDK and any other dependencies) you need.  Otherwise, if you've not been able to build *ANYTHING* with QT Creator ... I would run (not walk!) to AndroidStudio.   This link might also help: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html

Comment: AndroidStudio is another huge IDE. I downloaded it from here https://developer.android.com/studio, extracted, but I am not sure... If I am using Qt Creator IDE, why should I have AndroidStudio instead of just AndroidSDK to plug into Qt Creator? Havent giveup on Felgo yet, seems quite robust, still researching what to do anyway :>

Comment: If you want an IDE for Android, AndroidStudio is the one I'd recommend.  For many, many different reasons.  Nevertheless, you *DON'T* need an IDE to build any/all facets of an Android project, including generating an .apk.  You only need a) Java, b) Gradle, c) the Android SDK and d) your Android project.  A project generated by A/S should work fine; I would think QT Creator should also generate a viable project.  But the compile errors suggest your project isn't configured correctly :(

Comment: @veganEye we are looking at Felgo but all signs are the project is dead (Slack channel has no answers for months, community forums seems to lack any community).  Do you need Box2D or are you just building Android app?  Please update what you find.

Comment: @TSG oh... Felgo feels so robust, I haven't been able to make more tests lately tho as I was/am occupied with other things. I wanted, for current project, to make an android app (actually cross platform, I need it working at least on linux and android tho) that is essentially a list but feels better to use and interact, and should have notifications, save on google drive (like games does but this would not be a game) etc.

Comment: Felgo is a thin wrapper on Qt's QML product (QML is an impressive game platform in itself).  Much of what Felgo offers can be found in the open source community (eg: QML-BOX2D project) so that is worth a look as well.  At $1500/yr and frightening license terms, I'm not sure Felgo is the "best" way to generate an APK as requested by the OP.  Perhaps a look at pure Qt + QML-BOX2D projects would meet the OP's needs.  The QML-BOX2D projects has good support, so asking of that group may yield answer.  (Questions in Felgo forums/channel are largely unanswered) - perhaps Felgo project is dying

Comment: @TSG oh.. I am very new (noob) on all these smartphone coding. I certainly prefer open souce, I really didnt knew there was one that is easy to use/deploy projects. I will surely take a look at QML-BOX2D, thx vm! (tricky license terms scare me a lot too)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with pure Qt Creator (implement a simple game in QML).  Qt Creator has excellent online instructions and support on various forums.  If you need physics for 2d game consider adding QML-BOX2D.  (An open source add-on).

Felgo has wrapped some functions to save you a few steps, but their claim of 90% less code then other platforms is due to QML (little to do with Felgo).  Felgo forum posts from users are unanswered and the Felgo Slack channel shows unanswered questions going back months!  But it doesn't matter if Felgo is dying, you should still start with pure Qt / QML

The Qt site offers instructions for compiling to APK (see [Qt Android Instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html)), they even have helper classes for placing the executable in the app stores/selling.  Once you master QML (and possible QML-box2d) then you can look at some add-ons to make life a bit simpler.

I would however suggest you move to Qt5 - Qt4 is getting pretty old.  I'm not saying QML is the "best" game dev platform, but if Qt/QML/C++ checks your boxes then it is great and you should be able to build for Android fairly easily using the link above (instructions too long to copy into this answer)

Comment: Hi - Felgo is still here and it is the end of 2022. Though, not too many questions on their forum which is not a good sign. On SO 16 questions tagged with [felgo]. If it is dying, it is a slow death. I am currently evaluating qml vs. flutter as a cross platform mobile solution, and flutter is live and kicking (over 160k questions on SO). I haven't checked felgo's licensing terms. From their FAQ, if you stop paying, you stop deploying new versions.

Comment: From other links on the net, it seems that qml kicks ass when it comes to animation. But the JavaScript language throws me off.

Comment: Maybe felgo is so good that people figure things out and they don't need to ask questions ;-)

Comment: You don't need JavaSript for animation in QML.  You have a choice of how to control animation.  It looks like Felgo is a slowly sinking ship.  There does not appear to be any investment/development, and those same questions from 2+ years ago are still unanswered

Comment: re: JavaScript, I was referring in general. Though I am not disputing their choice of language. I actually like Qt a lot...

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine following the steps in this guide https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-deployment-android/#add-felgo-packages-for-android-platform

There is also Felgo Cloud Builds, you don't have to setup anything on your machine https://felgo.com/cloud-builds, even you can skip any install by using the WebIDE http://ide.felgo.com/

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.